# Can't hit breakpoint with new solution configuration

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015 I have two solution configurations 'Debug' and 'Services'.  I am able to debug and hit breakpoints with the Debug setting, but not with Services.

To isolate the issue, I have tried to make the Services config look exactly like the Debug config.  They both build the same projects and are both set for Any CPU.  The only difference I can see between the two at this point is their name.

What settings can cause a breakpoint to not be hit when I can do it with Debug but not Services?  And when I mean not 'hit', the breakpoint appears disabled when running as Services.

Running as Debug...

[image]

Running as Services...

[image]

Comment: Lemme guess... you're not generating PDBs in your 'Services' config?

Comment: Yep, that's the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is usually caused by one of two different problems.

First, you're not creating PDBs for the particular build configuration.  To fix, configure Debug Info for PDB only or Full.

[image]

Another possible problem is that the current project isn't configured to build for the current build configuration.  In the properties for the solution, make sure it's checked for the current configuration.

[image]

If these two don't work, close VS, delete all your bin folders, and try again.  If you're still stuck, you have a real problem.